# Installing pip in virtualenv using easy_install, for TensorFlow

Tags: macos, tensorflow, pip, virtualenv, easy-install

I'm starting to experiment with TensorFlow and am following the [TensorFlow guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) to installing on Mac OS X, using virtualenv as recommended.

The instructions essentially boil down to the following:

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
virtualenv --system-site-packages <mydirectory>
source ./<mydirectory>/bin/activate
easy_install -U pip
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

When I get to the `easy_install -U pip` step, I get the error:

"*`<mydirectory>`/bin/easy_install: `<mydirectory>`/bin/python: bad interpreter: permission denied"*.

I can't understand what's going on here. My (usual) user has full permissions to `<mydirectory>`, where I believe everything should be running.

I assume running an older version of pip is not big deal, but something obviously goes wrong when I try the `pip install --upgrade tensor flow` step, because when I try running a Python script that uses TensorFlow I get the exception "`import tensor flow as tf. Import error: no module named tensorflow`".

Some help would be much appreciated please :)

Comment: try adding `sudo` before `easy_install -U pip`

Comment: @palebone No, don't use `sudo` inside virtual env.

Comment: What is the result of running `<mydirectory>/bin/python` directly?

Comment: @phd Simply running `<mydirectory>/bin/python` gives me the details of the Python installation (version etc). I can then use the prompt from there to run Python commands. Hadn't thought of that as a troubleshooting step by the way, thanks.